# Use transform to translate a node until it reaches it's parent's position

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms, css-animations

Is there a way to improve **[my current implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/hEbb7/)** of an automated cell dynamic marquee. The current behavior matches the requirements, but is not as perfect as I would expect.

**Current behavior**

As shown in the demo, holding your mouse over an ellipsed cell, makes it into a *good old scrolling marquee*.

**Expected behaviour**

I'm trying to have my inner-wrapper-`span` stop scrolling when the rightmost part of the inner-wrapped-span reaches the rightmost part of the `td`.

The following code got me to the current "static" behaviour

```
100% {
    transform:translateX(-90%);
}
```

I use an arbitrary 90% because I don't know how I could use different units to achieve my goal. If you compare the result obtained in the first and third row, you'll notice that the `span` doesn't stop at the same portion of its "travel" depending on the length of its content (obviously because I use percentages).

I would think a solution would be similar to the following JQuery script :

```
var x = $(this).parent().width() - $(this).width();
$(this).addDynamicKeyframeDefinition("100%{ transform: translateX("+x+")}");
```

Unfortunatly the `addDynamicKeyframeDefinition` method doesn't exists. :-)

---

**EDIT** In light of [vals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals)'s suggestion

- The provided demo has a fixed table size, most of tables in the real project have dynamic column sizes. Thus the probable need to dynamically set a value for `translateeX()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more than one transform, and they can be of the same function:

```
@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform:translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateX(10px) translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

Will set the remaining space to 10px

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hEbb7/2/)

You can do what you want (translate the span until the right border adjusts to the container div border) using a wrapper (another one).

I have created a simple demo so that you can see the technique.

For this HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td><div><span>aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbb ccccc dddddd</span></div></td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td><div><span>aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbb ccccc dddddd  eee fff ggg hhh jjjjj j</span></div></td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is

```
table {
    width: 356px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    position: relative;
}

div {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 2s;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(160,255,200,0.4);
    transition: all 2s;
}
td:hover div {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
td:hover span {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

The first wrapper (the div) is set to 100% width. translating it to 100% sets its left border to the right of the parent.
Now, translating the span -100%, moves the right border to the left border of the div, and so to the right border of the td.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSHtm/1/)

The div and the span have colored border and background so that the effect is visible.

Comment: Thank you @vals, you thought me something useful! Although, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. :-( I would like to have it stop scrolling when the rightmost part of the inner-wrapped-span reaches the rightmost part of the td. In the production project the size of column is rarely fixed thus my question targeting a dynamic way to populate the translateX function. I'll add those precision to the question. Thanks again!

Comment: added another solution (more adjusted to what you want)

Comment: Good job, I'm impressed your solution doesn't even include JQuery. The "trick" you used is also quite brilliant! Thanks alot! :-)

Comment: For future reference, here's your solution applied to my demo context : http://jsfiddle.net/hEbb7/4/